# gWidgets return multiple responses for multiple columns

Tags: arrays, gwidgets

I posted before on this and was not able to arrive at a solution with the single posted response.  I have tried another approach that gets me what I want, mostly.  The current solution would work better if it were in a single dialogue box but I am not sure how to do this.  I am putting together other solutions I found on Nabble and stack and just cannot get what I need.  I want the following to offer the choices in a single window, instead of having the user input into 3 separate boxes.  Please help.

```
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
library(gWidgets)
#Creat selection function
select <- function(x,multiple = TRUE, Title,...){
  ans<-new.env()

  x1<-ggroup(horizontal=TRUE) # no parent container here
  x2<-gcheckboxgroup( x,multiple=multiple,con=x1,expand=TRUE)
  ret <- gbasicdialog(title = Title, widget=x1,handler=function(h,...){
    value <- svalue(x2)
    if (length(value)==0) value=""
    assign("selected",value,env=h$action$env)
    dispose(x1)
  },action=list(env=ans))
  ans
}   
#Create list to store results
Days. <- c("Day1","Day2","Day3")
Outputs_ <- list()
SelectionOptions. <- c("Bicycle Event1", "Construction Nearby","Path Closure")

#Cycle through each day 
for(day in Days.){      
    ans <- select(SelectionOptions., Title = day)
    Outputs_[[day]] <- ans$selected
}
#return results of selection
unlist(Outputs_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it a bit more complicated than need be.

- you are better off making things asynchronous (in most cases), using a handler to be called when the values are selected.
- However, if you want it done this way, make a container for your selection widgets, then add them to the container. This container is then passed into gbasicdialog. That way all will show in one window. Using `gWidgets2` makes working with the basic dialog a lot easier.

Comment: I have really been struggling with the widget package, you think you can provide a working example?  Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is an example, though I'm not quite sure what problem you are trying to solve, so may be off:

```
library(gWidgets2)

Days. <- c("Day1","Day2","Day3")
SelectionOptions. <- c("Bicycle Event1", "Construction Nearby","Path Closure")

w <- gwindow()
g <- gformlayout(cont=w)
days <- gradio(Days., cont=g, label="Days:")
opts <- gcombobox(SelectionOptions., cont=g, label="Options:")

btn <- gbutton("Show them", cont=g, label="")

addHandlerClicked(btn, handler=function(h,...) {
    values <- lapply(list(days, opts), svalue)
    print(values)
})

## or using a modal dialog

dlg <- gbasicdialog(handler=function(h,...) {
    values <- lapply(list(days, opts), svalue)
    print(values)
})
g <- gformlayout(cont=dlg)
days <- gradio(Days., cont=g, label="Days:")
opts <- gcombobox(SelectionOptions., cont=g, label="Options:")
visible(dlg, TRUE)

## third time is a charm? (Though you could clean this up)
library(gWidgets2)
e <- new.env()
e$Days <- ""; e$Sel <- ""

Days. <- c("Day1","Day2","Day3")
SelectionOptions. <- c("Bicycle Event1", "Construction Nearby","Path Closure")

dlg <- gbasicdialog(title="test", do.buttons=FALSE)
g <- ggroup(cont=dlg, horizontal=FALSE)

fl <- gformlayout(cont=g)
days <- gradio(Days., cont=fl, label="Days:")
cb <- gcombobox(SelectionOptions., selected=0, cont=fl, label="Options:")

handler <- function(h,...) {
    e$Days <- svalue(days)
    e$Sel <- ifelse(length(svalue(cb)) > 0, svalue(cb), "")
    if (all(sapply(e, function(x) nchar(x) > 0)))
        dlg$dispose_window()
}
sapply(list(days, cb), addHandlerChanged, handler=handler)
visible(dlg, TRUE)
```

### Take 4

```
library(gWidgets2)
days <- paste("Day", 1:3)
events <- c("none", "Bicycle Event","Construction Nearby","Path Closure")
l <- list()

handler <- function(h,...) {
    l[[h$action]] <<- svalue(h$obj)
    if(length(l) == 3)
        print(l)
}

w <- gwindow()
g <- gvbox(cont=w)
for (day in days) {
    l <- glabel(day, cont=g); font(l) <- list(weight="bold")
    gradio(events, cont=g, handler=handler, action=day)
}
```

Comment: The example you provided doesn;t seem to work for me.  It appears something needs to be set differently in either gwindow or gformlayout.  Just to be sure, the problem I am trying to solve is to create a pop-up window that halts my process until check boxes are selected for multiple items.

Comment: The second form with `gbasicdialog` will do that. You would want to add handlers to the controls likes `days` and `opts` to check when all controls have a selection. I've added that to the example.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  gformlayout still doesn;t seem to be building correctly.  I get the error:Error in .makeForm(lst, mainGroup, e) : 
  argument "lst" is missing, with no default

Comment: Make sure you are trying `gWidgets2` -- not `gWidgets`.

Comment: I did get the example to work, you were right I was loading gWidgets2 library whihc casued problems but the other thing I needed to do was load the library

Comment: I did get the example to work, you were right I was loading gWidgets2 library which caused problems but the other thing I needed to do was load the library "gWidgets2RGtk2". Even though I got the example working it doesn't get me where I want.  What I want is something like the silly survey monkey link - https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/F3Z79MM   the result would be a table with each day having an element or a list that includes multiple elements that would look something like: the next comment

Comment: Results.. <- data.frame(Day = Days.)
Results..$Event <- list(c("Bicycle Event1","Construction Nearby"),"PathClosure","Bicycle Event1")

Comment: Okay, I added "Take 4" to do this. Some room for improvement: there isn't a radio option without some initial selection so I added "none" (you might use a different control); the check that all fields are filled out in the handler could be improved; how you want to store the selected values may differ.